# how to show a rounded decimal in a decimal form field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a decimal form field.  When the instance is showing I want it to show a value of 60.1 instead of 60.1111. The model field is to 4 decimal places.

I know I can change the date format like this:

```
class AccountPersonalInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer

    fields = ( 
              'amount',
              'birth_date', 
            )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AccountPersonalInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['birth_date'].widget.format = '%B %d, %Y'
    self.fields['birth_date'].input_formats = ['%B %d, %Y']

    #can I round the decimal format here?
    self.fields['amount'].widget.format = ???
```

How can I round the decimal that show in a decimal field to 1 decimal place when the model field is to 4  decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

You can limiting floats digit after the decimal point to one by using `round` or  `float("{0:.1f}".`

Check:

```
x= 60.1111
g = float("{0:.1f}".format(x))
h = round(x, 1)

print h,g
```

Comment: how can i do this in the above form?